# wicked_pdf handlebars/mustache support

Tags: wicked-pdf

I've used wicked_pdf with erb before, but I'm now wanting to use wicked_pdf leveraging handlebars as my template engine.

Should that just work with wicked_pdf? I see questions with haml tags, so I'm assuming yes.  Just wondering if anyone else has tried.

On a side note - Is anyone using presenters with wicked_pdf?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work.

WickedPdf merely hooks into the Rails 'render' method, so anything it can do, can be done with wicked_pdf.

Answer (score 0):

When I use haml I do the following, perhaps something similar is possible with handlebars.

```
def [action-name]
  ...
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.pdf do
      render :pdf => 'filename',
             :handlers => [:haml]
    end
  end
end
```